# Include someone's comment to your answer, in your answer

Tags: discussion, answers, comment, etiquette

If you provide an answer, and someone comments on it with another piece of evidence in favor of your answer, but different, is it appropriate to include that comment in your answer and recognize the commenter with @username?

I couldn't find this topic while searching, so feel free to link me to past discussions or threads if relevant.

Comment: I'd say if there are no or very few comments under your answer, it's usually enough to upvote that comment and leave a response comment saying that you agree & it's an important contribution. If there are many comments already then one might worry that future readers will not notice that important comment; then I don't see anything wrong with copy-pasting it into your answer (formatting it as a quote and certainly giving an attribution). Sometimes people update their answers elaborating on (as opposed to copy-pasting) somebody's comment. That is also fine.

Comment: Ok, that's fair and along the lines of what I was thinking. Just wanted to confirm.

Comment: But what if the person thinks that it is so relevant and different that he decides to submit a separate question.  If you include it in your answer even though you give him credit that might discourage him from submitting  the answer. Rewarding his comment with a + vote does not help his reputation.

Comment: @Michael Chernick I can't see a real problem. Anyone who choses to comment rather than answer won't gain in reputation; that is correct. I can't say that ever influences my contributions.  The implication is that people should write  some good answers somewhere if they wish to gain reputation.  Anything else looks like second-guessing about what upsets or motivates people. Anyone upset by their comment being quoted but not otherwise matched by reputation gain is not going to enjoy the site for long. Reputation is only an elaborate game with some bizarre details and several positive features.

Answer (score 3):

I'd have to say that I don't understand why people don't answer questions using the answer section instead of the comments sections.  Your post is a good example.  Ha!

I think we should remove comments that answer questions, and ask users to enter these answers in the answer section, where they belong.

Check this out:  [Bounty Question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253335/plsa-model-confusion)

```
@conjugateprior, could you help to add a reply, so that it could  
 benefit other people. I will mark it as answer and grant bounty  
 points. :) – Lin Ma 17 hours ago
```

Comment: I disagree strongly with the recommendation to remove comments that answer questions. That could be discussed at length, but it's sufficient to note that no one could remove comments except moderators and it's emphatically not part of their job to decide what answers a question.

Comment: I agree that often it would be good if a good comment were made into an answer.  I have on occasion appreciated encouragement to do that, but sometimes also one lacks the time or the inclination.

Comment: I agree with you Nick, but that has not stopped many moderators from doing just that.  I also agree that I do not have time to write strong, lengthy answers, so maybe the site's requirements of answers could be weakened a bit to encourage short, precise answers to questions.

Comment: I don't see any examples of "moderators ... doing just that". It's entirely in order for moderators acting as members here to imply personal endorsement of particular answers, but there is no such approbation implied by their role.